# Windows Phone 8.1 Page Navigation Method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, navigationservice

I have gone through some code and got familiar with Navigation Service in Windows Phone 8.1. But I need this code to declare in my Base Page to use it every where in all other pages, declaring the code only one.

For example, from the following code,

```
    protected void NavigateToPage(string uri)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

I just pass the Uri of the page in **NavigateToPage(PageUri)** to achieve my target. But how i could i achieve this in Windows Phone 8.1. This is what I tried,

```
    protected void NavigateToPage(Type sourcePage)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(sourcePage));
    }
```

But I couldn't use sourcePage here. May be I am doing wrong with the Type of parameter. Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this:

```
protected void NavigateToPage(Type sourcePage)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(sourcePage);
}
```